# Yaml merge ignoring properties defined in anchor

Tags: java, merge, yaml, snakeyaml

Consider this yaml

```
- node_1:
    properties: &node_1_prop
      role: management
      layer: 1

- node_2:
    properties:
      level:  24
      <<: *node_1_prop
```

I am trying to create node graph using `snakeyaml` library and I am expecting two properties for `node_1` and three for `node_2` like [this](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/?yaml=-%20node_1%3A%0A%20%20%20%20properties%3A%20%26node_1_prop%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20role%3A%20management%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20layer%3A%201%0A%0A-%20node_2%3A%0A%20%20%20%20properties%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20level%3A%20%2024%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%3C%3A%20*node_1_prop&type=json).

```
Path yamlPath = Paths.get( "nodes.yaml");
InputStream yamlStream = Files.newInputStream(yamlPath);
StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(new UnicodeReader(yamlStream));
Composer composer = new Composer(new ParserImpl(sreader), new Resolver());
Node rootNode = composer.getSingleNode();
```

The output node graph by snakeyaml is showing `<<` as property for `node_2`.

Code example showing the result on [Git](https://github.com/ubersmart/snakeyaml-bug).

**Edit:**

Nodes gets constructed fine if I define the yaml as below:

```
- node_1:
    properties: &node_1_prop
      role: management
      layer: 1

- node_2:
      <<: *node_1_prop
```

However my requirement is not just copy the properties as it is but to have additional properties.

Comment: @Anthon I tried that as well but same result. You can download the code from Git and try few things if you want. My guess is, it's a bug in library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not load your YAML completely, you only *compose* it (see [graph in the YAML 1.1 spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id859109) which SnakeYaml implements).

The compose step resolves aliases, but keeps the tags – tags are resolved during construction. The merge key is defined [as a tag](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) and thus, does not get processed when you compose the YAML input.

Comment: How do I construct the nodes? Am I missing any step? I updated my answer to have another example where during composing proper nodes get created, removing tags.

Comment: Well I don't know the actual implementation, I only answered based on what is *supposed* to be happening based on the spec. I can't really tell you why the other example is working. Anyway, construction is done via `(new Yaml()).load(input)`, you'll get standard Java types from it  (`List`, `Map` or `String` depending on the root node). This is covered in [the docs](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation) in detail.

Comment: Also mind that the merge key is outside the original YAML definition of what tags are. They should map to native types, however, `!!merge` (or the associated key) maps to a processing instruction which does not really exist in YAML. Since there is no advice on implementation, you can expect strange behavior and I would advice against using it.

Comment: if you add to your git code
List<String> prop3 = node_2_props.getValue().stream()
                .map(prop -> ((ScalarNode) prop.getKeyNode()).getTag().getValue())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("Node_3 properties: " + prop3);
You will see that node's tag is merge.
The Constructor deals with merging, but is @flyx correctly said: you only compose nodes.